# How to grab hex value in between a bunch of zeros and convert it to decimal?

Tags: python, type-conversion, hex

I wanted to try and grab a hex value in between a bunch of zeros and convert it to decimal. Here's a sample: '00000000002E3706400000'. So I only want to grab '2E37064' and disregard everything else around it. I know to use the `int()` function to convert it to decimal, but when I do, it includes the leading zeros right after the actual hex value. Here's a sample of my code:

```
hex_val = '00000000002E3706400000'
dec_val = int(hex_val, 16)
print(dec_val)
```

And then here's the output:

```
50813862936576
```

The actual value I want is:

```
48459876
```

Is there an optimal way to accomplish this?

Comment: `.strip(0)`? But they _are_ part of the value.

Comment: …so `50813862936576` *is* the correct answer.

Comment: What are the rules here? Is it always exactly that number? Then do it manually. Is it a certain position in the string? How are we to know that the zero following the 4 isn't part of the hex  number - 0 is hex after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.strip()` function to remove the leading and trailing zeroes (though removing the leading zeroes here isn't technically necessary):

```py
int(hex_val.strip('0'), 16)
```

This outputs:

```py
48459876
```